# Assembly Language - finding the largest number in an array

Tags: assembly, x86

I've written this program and each time I compile it returns 0 for the edx register which is where my largest value should be going. I also had to force the eax and ecx register by one to have the correct answer, as you will see. I have attempted multiple things to try and get the edx to populate anything other than 0, with no luck.

```
TITLE SUM & AVERAGE & LARGEST    (Program2.asm)

COMMENT !

2nd Program - Sum, Avg, Largest
CS340 Summer 2020
This program places an array of numbers to find the sum, avg, and largest.
!

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;; sum = eax,  avg = ebx,  remainder = ecx, largest = edx ;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


.data
ary   dword 50,-20,34,14,45,-37,82,134,83  ; Array to hold the required values
      dword 59,-24,1,-19,30,55,81,74,83,0
cnt   dword ?                              ; Count value holder
lrg   dword ?                              ; Largest value holder
reset dword 0                              ; Reset value to avoid garbage

.code
main PROC

   ;Clearing the Registries 
    mov eax, reset              ; Clears the registry and places 0 into memory
    mov ebx, reset              ; Clears the registry and places 0 into memory
    mov ecx, reset              ; Clears the registry and places 0 into memory
    mov edx, reset              ; Clears the registry and places 0 into memory

   ;Start of the program
    mov esi, offset ary         ; Places the address of ary into esi


Sum:                            ; Loop for Sum
    add eax, [esi]              ; Sums all the numbers
    inc cnt                     ; Adds one to count
    add esi, 4                  ; Bump pointer by one dword(4 bytes)
    cmp ebx, [esi]              ; Compare value of esi to ebx 
    jne Sum                     ; Jump back to the top if not equal to sum

    mov ecx, eax                ; Moves eax(total) into ecx(remainder)
    inc ecx         
    inc eax         

Avg:                            ; Loop for Average
    sub ecx, cnt                ; Subtract count from ecx
    inc ebx                     ; Adds one to ebx
    cmp ecx, cnt                ; Compares count to the value of ecx
    jg  Avg                     ; Jump to Avg if value is greater than 

Largest:
    mov edx, [esi]              ; Places the value of esi into edx
    cmp lrg, edx                ; Places the value in edx into largest 
    jl  Temp 
    cmp edx, 0              ; Compares 0 to the value within edx    
    jne Largest                 ; Jump, if not equal, to Sum

Temp:
    mov lrg, edx
    cmp edx, 0
    jne Largest


    call    DumpRegs            ; display the registers

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Single step your code with a debugger.  Look where `jne Largest` falls through to, if you *do* exit the loop from the one before `Temp`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to load a `0` from memory to zero a register.  Use an immediate, or just `xor eax,eax` is the preferred way to zero a reg. Also, x86 has `idiv` for signed division; you don't need a repeated-subtraction loop.  (Which will fail if the average is negative.)

Comment: A restriction for this assignment is we're unable to use any sort of division. Would you mind showing the syntax of what you mean? I'm very green to assembly, it's easier to understand when I see the code.

Comment: I'm not confident on stepping through the debugger. I am new to visual studios as well. There's an Irvine website we are using for the book and theres a small article on stepping though, but I don't follow.

Comment: The only way to get confident using a debugger is to use a debugger. Consider what value `esi` points to at the beginning of the `Largest` loop (hint: refer to your first loop where you calculate the sum).

Comment: We don't mind if it's a school assignment or not (as long as the question is good) but you should mention it in your post so we know some restrictions apply. (Such as: write this in C and let the compiler work it out.)